# java getting error while using implements

Tags: java, implements

Am new to java so please help me to solve my problem.
Here is my code for printing the reciept bill

```
public  class BillPrintable implements Printable{

public int print(Graphics graphics,PageFormat pageformat,int pageIndex)throws PrinterException
    {
        int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        if(pageIndex == 0)
        {
            Graphics2D g2d= (Graphics2D) graphics;
            double width = pageformat.getImageableWidth();
            g2d.translate((int) pageformat.getImageableX(), (int) pageformat.getImageableY());
            FontMetrics metrics=g2d.getFontMetrics(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,7));
            int idLength=metrics.stringWidth("000");
            int amtLength=metrics.stringWidth("000000");
            int qtyLength=metrics.stringWidth("000000");
            int priceLength=metrics.stringWidth("00000");
            int prodLength=(int)width-idLength-amtLength-priceLength-17;

            int productPosition = 0;
            int discountPosition=prodLength+0;
            int pricePosition =discountPosition+idLength + 10;
            int qtyPosition = pricePosition + priceLength + 4;
            int amtPosition = qtyPosition + qtyLength;
            try {
                int y=20;
                int yShift = 10;
                int headerRectHeight = 15;
                int headerRectHeighta = 40;
                g2d.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN,9));
                g2d.drawString("............................", 12, y);y+=yShift;
                g2d.drawString("  Restaurant Bill Reciept   ", 12, y);y+=yShift;
                g2d.drawString("----------------------------", 12, y);y+=headerRectHeighta;


                g2d.drawString("......................................", 10, y);y+=yShift;


                g2d.drawString("......................................", 10, y);;y+=yShift;

                g2d.drawString("          Free Home Delivery          ", 10, y);;y+=yShift;
                g2d.drawString("             9895776277               ", 10, y);;y+=yShift;
                g2d.drawString("......................................", 10, y);;y+=yShift;
                g2d.drawString("      Thanks To Visit Our Restaurant  ", 10, y);;y+=yShift;
                g2d.drawString("......................................", 10, y);;y+=yShift;

            }
            catch(Exception r)
            {
                r.printStackTrace();
            }
            result = PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Here the error i got is like this `The type bill.BillPrintable must implement the inherited abstract method Printable.print(Graphics, PageFormat, int)`.Dont know how the problem arises and how to solve the problem.please help me to solve thanks in advance
This is my imported statements.please have a look

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javafx.print.Paper;
import com.sun.prism.Graphics;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat.*;
import java.awt.print.Paper.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
```

Comment: Do oyu have imported wrong class?

Comment: can you add your import statements? that might help.

Comment: No its not a wrong class

Comment: @germi yaa sure

Comment: there is only one Printable interface: ***java.awt.print.Printable;***  where is the instance of the BillPrintable getting used....

Comment: Not what you asked, but you should _never_ use the form of `import` with the asterisk.  Import exactly the classes that you need, and never a whole package at a time.  [This article](http://javadude.com/articles/importondemandisevil.html) explains why - basically, using the asterisk creates the potential for your code to stop working in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You import class `Graphics` from a wrong package:

```
import com.sun.prism.Graphics
```

must be

```
import java.awt.Graphics
```

Also the following imports are unessasary:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat.*;
import java.awt.print.Paper.*;
```

Pay attention: You should not use `com.sun` classes directly

Answer (score 0):

THe error is that to override the method `print(Graphics, PageFormat, int)`, which is inherited from parent class. The parameters should be same of parent method, or java will this it as declaring a new method,rather than to override the method. This method is static too,so you can call this method,without instantiating the class.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics from Wrong package

 
Please try with this

```
import java.awt.Graphics
```